# Visual Studio Code shows administrator in title bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just had a fresh install from windows 10 to windows 7 and installed VSCode and now it says in the tile bar as Visual Studio Code [Administrator]. I have the system setup installed and not the user setup. I am the only one who uses this PC and only has one account. Could someone help me figure this out?
[image: VSCODE]

Answer (score 0):

You started Visual Studio Code with administrator rights (e.g. right click on the VSC icon and select `Start as administrator` or similar) or you Windows user account is an administrator accounts (have a look in your Windows user list).

Comment: There is only one acc - mine, which is an admin